# ImportError: cannot import name 'register_load_context_function' from 'tensorflow.python.util.keras_deps'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
```

I was running these lines on jupyter notebook.
I received this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'register_load_context_function' 
from 'tensorflow.python.util.keras_deps' 
(C:\Users\chandana mohan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\keras_deps.py)
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your tensorflow version.

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for both Python 2 and Python 3
```